# Difference between DESede and TripleDES for cipher.getInstance()

Tags: java, cryptography, encryption, tripledes

I am trying to get TripleDES encryption working in Java. From the [Wikipedia article](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Triple_DES) under `Keying Options`, I want to use option 1, where `All three keys are independent`.

From the [Cipher docs](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/javax/crypto/Cipher.html) it says to go to the [reference guide here](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/technotes/guides/security/crypto/CryptoSpec.html#AppA), but it still isn't clear to me.

I am working on getting examples running, and use both of these lines in different projects:

```
Cipher c = Cipher.getInstance("DESede");

Cipher cipher = Cipher.getInstance("TripleDES/ECB/PKCS5Padding");
```

Both compile fine, so what's the difference? Should I be using one over the other? Do both of these work for using three separate keys?

Answer (score 40, accepted):

"TripleDES" is simply an alias for "DESede" in the Sun JCE provider – both return the exact same cipher. "DESede" is the standard name which should work on every Java platform, but in practice, "TripleDES" is probably pretty widely supported too.

According to [this page](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/technotes/guides/security/SunProviders.html), the SunJCE Triple DES implementation supports options #1 and #2:

> Keysize must be equal to 112 or 168.
>
> A keysize of 112 will generate a Triple DES key with 2 intermediate keys, and a keysize of 168 will generate a Triple DES key with 3 intermediate keys.

You should always specify the mode of operation and the padding when instantiating a cipher to make your intents clear. Otherwise the implementation is free to make the choice, which can be confusing.

Comment: DESede is descriptive name for 3DES implementation: DESede = DES-Encrypt-Decrypt-Encrypt = Triple DES