# Decryption on java side

Tags: javascript, java, cryptojs

I found core library and Now I can encrypt and decrypt on Jsp

```
var encryptedpassword=CryptoJS.AES.encrypt(password,'abcd');
var ciphertext = encryptedpassword.ciphertext.toString(CryptoJS.enc.Base64);
console.log(ciphertext);
```

and decrypted using following

```
var decryptedpassword=CryptoJS.AES.decrypt(encryptedpassword,'abcd');
var plaintext = decryptedpassword.toString(CryptoJS.enc.Utf8);
console.log(plaintext);
```

My problem now is I want to decrypt the encrypted password on java side can some one tell me how can I do it?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Encrypt and Decrypt in Java](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10303767/encrypt-and-decrypt-in-java)

Comment: I am having fixed key on jsp so how can it be implemented on java