# Safe storing passwords for user's mailbox

Tags: java, database, email, passwords

I know there are dozens of topics about storing a passwords in DB, but all of them are missing one approach: what if I want to use this password to authenticate my app to an external service?

Today I'm making a mailbox module to my app and here's where I've bumped a wall. How to store a password to the user's mailbox, so the server of my app can read it from database, make a call to mail server and get messages?

If I'll store it as plain text - it's obvious suicide.
If I'll encrypt it (hash) - it's unreversible so I can't properly sign in to mail server.

What to do?? Help please! :)

Thank you in advance and best regards,
Tom

Comment: If you already store passwords *in* DB, why not store the mail password there too? --- Or did you mean "storing a passwords *for connecting to* DB"? If so, why not store the mail password in the same place as the DB passwords?

Comment: I am storing a passwords used for app authentication. They are hashed/salted and during the log in - password is hashed/salted on client side and compared with the one stored in DB. That's ok.

But... The user can also enter his/hers mail server settings so the mailbox will be read and he/she can read/reply/compose mail etc. And with the password for mailbox I have a problem.

Comment: Then you need to *encrypt*, not *hash*, the email password.

Comment: What I mean by the above is that a app engine is to perform periodic check if there's new mail etc. So the engine needs to call a mail server and introduce itself with username and password entered by user and stored in database. What I'm trying to do here is to avoid storing a plain-text password in database.

Comment: `encrypt =/= hash`, one is reversible, the other is not.

Comment: Now I get it :) To be honest - I've always thought it's one, same thing :)

Comment: I've found some info on that. Do you think this will fit my needs? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10303767/encrypt-and-decrypt-in-java