# Can I encrypt just some fields of an object using Realm Database?

Tags: android, database, encryption, realm

I have a realm object with sensitive and not sensitive fields and I wanna encrypt just some fields of my object. Is it possible to do it in Realm database?

Answer (score 1):

Realm encryption applies to the whole database. To encrypt specific columns in your database you will need to roll your own encryption. There is some discussion using the javax.crypto library  [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/10316509/5528313)